# Distributed app without external server design problem

Tags: android, sockets, architecture, network-programming

I am trying to figure out good design for an android app that is ment to communicate with same app on other phones.

Lets assume following scenario, 4 people meet and they want to connect thier phones together to share some messages between them. I have decided to try out following approach: One of them creates a group 3 other people will join. Creating a group essentially will start a server and open a socket. How remaining 3 apps can find out how to connect to the newly created server?

I have considered using bluetooth, but as far as i know it is limited to only a few devices. Manually sending IP addresses to eachother seems to be an option, but thats not what an app should do. External server would be a solution to this problem, but the entire point is to avoid having that.

What would be a possible solutions for apps discovery?

Comment: Connect to each other how? Bluetooth? Wifi? Mobile data?

Comment: That is pretty much my question, i want them to exchange data. Not realy sure what is the proper way to do that nowadays.

Comment: Bluetooth scatternet looks interesting. But no, I'm not the expert here, just curious about your question and possible answers.

Comment: I'm curious about this too. You should look into how Nintendo did this back in the day with the Gameboy DS. I recall it being very stable, easy to use and I believe it was over WiFi.